# PROCESS (Hayes) by using IV categorical

Tags: interaction

I am trying to run a moderation using SPSS with Hayes'macro. But I have a IV with 3 categories (a,b,c). In his page Hayes gives this explanation (see below) but I am not sure how to do this using SPSS. I have run moderation with IV with 2 categories and having no problems (there is a good tutorial by Andy Field). So far the best solution I came up with is to create 2 data sets, one data set having 2 groups (a,b) and then run a moderation and another data set having 2 groups (a,c) and run another moderation. I am using "a" as my reference group. Am I doing it completely wrong? Thanks for your help.

“I have a categorical IV with more than two categories.  Can I still use SOBEL, INDIRECT or PROCESS?

It is possible with PROCESS or INDIRECT but not with SOBEL.  Using PROCESS or INDIRECT, the best approach is to dummy code the categorical IV.  If your IV has k categories, construct k-1 dummy variables and then run INDIRECT or PROCESS k-1 times.  With each run, make one dummy variable the IV and the other one(s) the covariate(s).  You will not get a single test of the indirect effect, but you will get indirect effects for each category relative to the reference category in the dummy coding scheme.  See the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anna,

To use PROCESS with a multicategorical IV, you first need to recode it into two dummy variables. If 'a' is the reference, one dummy should be a recode of the IV so that 'b' equals 1 and both 'a' and 'c' equal 0. The second dummy should be a recode of the IV so that 'c' equals 1 and both 'a' and 'b' equal 0.

Once you have these dummies, you can run PROCESS as follows:

PROCESS varlist= dummy1 dummy2 mod dv /x=dummy1 /m=mod /y=dv /model=1.

Note that while you do include the second dummy variable, it is not specified as either an IV, a DV, or a moderator. In this case, PROCESS considers it a covariate, and the output will indicate the effect of the first dummy on the DV while controlling for the effect of the second dummy. To find the effect of the second dummy variable, simply swap the dummy variables around.